# Excel VBA split CSV files a certain order

Tags: excel, vba, csv, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

This codes takes a CSV file such as:

```
"Penn National Gaming, Inc.",16.28
"iShares 20 Year Treasury Bond E",118.88
"iShares MSCI Emerging Index Fun",42.40
```

**Step 1**

*Line 0:* ""Penn National Gaming, Inc.",16.28

*Line 1:* "iShares 20 Year Treasury Bond E",118.88

*Line 2:* "iShares MSCI Emerging Index Fun",42.40

**Step 2**

It takes *Line 0* and makes it in:

*Value 0:*  Penn National Gaming

*Value 1:* , Inc.

*Value 2:* 16.28

**My question is: How can I make it as:**

*Value 0:*  Penn National Gaming Inc.

*Value 1:* 16.28

Essentially combine the full name (it may contain more than 1 comma) in *Value 0* and keep *value 1* as it is, but at the same time, still manage to comma separate the CSV delivered data. I was thinking of some sort of order (remove just 1 comma from *Line 1* starting from end to beginning of the line, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Thanks!

```
Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.ResponseText
Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbLf)
Dim sLine As String
Dim Values As Variant

For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
    sLine = Lines(i)
       If InStr(sLine, ",") > 0 Then
        Values = Split(sLine, ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting problem. I came up with a general function that will work for any number of non-quoted and quoted values in a csv line, where the quoted values may or may not contain commas.

**Test Line:** `"Penn National Gaming, Inc.",16.28`
**Output:**

```
    Value[0] = Penn National Gaming, Inc.  
    Value[1] = 16.28
```

**Test Line:** `a,b,c,"some, commas, here",16.28,"some,commas,there",17.123`
**Output:**

```
    Value[0] = a  
    Value[1] = b  
    Value[2] = c  
    Value[3] = some, commas, here  
    Value[4] = 16.28  
    Value[5] = some,commas,there  
    Value[6] = 17.123
```

1. I first searched the line for pairs of quotes "...".
2. Within each pair of quotes, I searched for commas, and replaced them with a character that I assume will never be present normally, `replacementCharacter = "¯"`, (you can choose a different character if you need to).
3. Once the quoted commas were replaced, i split the line by commas using the `Split()` function.
4. Then I iterated through the resulting array and replaced all replacementCharacters with commas.

I tested my code using the specific example given and a more general example of mixed quoted comma values, and values:

**Code:**

```
Function parseLine(sLine)
    Dim Value As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    quote = """"
    delimiter = ","
    replacementCharacter = "¯"

    'get first pair of quotes
    currentQuoteIndex = InStr(1, sLine, quote) 'get first quote
    If (currentQuoteIndex = 0) Then
        nextQuoteIndex = 0
    Else
        nextQuoteIndex = InStr(currentQuoteIndex + 1, sLine, quote) 'get next quote
    End If

    'get pairs of quotes and replace commas with replacementCharacter
    Do While nextQuoteIndex <> 0 And currentQuoteIndex <> 0

        subString = Mid(sLine, currentQuoteIndex + 1, nextQuoteIndex - currentQuoteIndex - 1)
        subString = Replace(subString, comma, replacementCharacter)
        sLine = Left(sLine, currentQuoteIndex - 1) + subString + Right(Mid(sLine, nextQuoteIndex + 1), Len(sLine))

        'get next pair of quotes
        currentQuoteIndex = InStr(nextQuoteIndex + 1, sLine, quote) 'get first quote
        If (currentQuoteIndex = 0) Then
            nextQuoteIndex = 0
        Else
            nextQuoteIndex = InStr(currentQuoteIndex + 1, sLine, quote)  'get next quote
        End If
    Loop

    'split string by commas
    Values = Split(sLine, delimiter)

    'replace replacementCharacter with commas
    For i = 0 To UBound(Values)
        Values(i) = Replace(Values(i), replacementCharacter, delimiter)
    Next
    parseLine = Values
End Function
```

This function works any number of comma containing quoted strings, with columns in any order.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried integrating it, however it did not work for some reason. The values 0,1 & 2 are still the same and 1 & 2 are not grouped.
Do you know what may be the reason and could you please give me some guidance in regards to actual integration with my full code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following **simple solution** identifies the location of the last comma.  This information is used to determine the location of the *full name* and *price* within the line.  The end result is an array containing 2 values.

> Note: Additional commas in *full name* are disregarded due to the non-split on comma "," process used

```
Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.ResponseText
Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbLf)
Dim sLine As String
Dim Values(1) As Variant

For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
    sLine = Lines(i)   

    'Reduced complexity by avoiding the need to split on commas ","
    Values(0) = left(sLine,instrrev(sLine,",")-1)  'Full Name
    Values(1) = mid(sLine,instrrev(sLine,",")+1)   'Price value
Next
```

**Using a Function**

```
Dim Resp As String: Resp = Http.ResponseText
Dim Lines As Variant: Lines = Split(Resp, vbLf)
Dim sLine As String
Dim Values(1) As Variant

Function extractData(sLine as String)
  Dim tmpArray(1) As Variant

  'Reduced complexity by avoiding the need to split on commas ","
  tmpArray(0) = left(sLine,instrrev(sLine,",")-1)  'Full Name
  tmpArray(1) = mid(sLine,instrrev(sLine,",")+1)   'Price value

  extractData = tmpArray

End Function

For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
    sLine = Lines(i)   
    Values = extractData(sLine)
Next
```

**Output:**

Value 0: Penn National Gaming, Inc.

Value 1: 16.28

Comment: Hi @Stelian if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: this does not provide a general solution. Note that OP says strings may come in a format as follows: ""Penn National Gaming, Inc.",16.28 "iShares 20 Year Treasury Bond E",118.88 "iShares MSCI Emerging Index Fun",42.40. Your solution should be able to parse the line and turn it into an array.

Comment: This is a point solution based upon the code and example provided by the OP.  You are correct, my solution would process each line of the CSV file.  With closer inspection of the OPs post, one would notice the example "Penn National Gaming, Inc.",16.28 "iShares 20 Year Treasury Bond E",118.88 "iShares MSCI Emerging Index Fun",42.40 are spread across multiple lines with vbLf.  Due to formatting, this was only visible from the edit mode.  I will place the code within the proper container i.e. code block, to properly illustrate the OP intentions. Let me know if you have any other concerns. @Brino

Comment: good catch. Sometimes SO includes/excludes whitespace characters in its posts.

Comment: When integrating this code, I gete Type Mismatch on the fist line of `Values(0)` etc.
Do you know why?

Comment: In the original code Values is a variable and it is changed to an array when split function is called.  In my solution, Values must be explicitly set.  This is denoted by the line **Dim Values(1) As Variant**